# How to work properly with assumptions?

Tags: series-expansion, assumptions

I'm trying to find an analytical solution which depends only of $i,j$ and $a$ variables, for a serie considering some initial assumptions.

The series is

$$s_{i0}=s_{0j} = 1,\\ s_{11} = 1-a,\\ s_{12} = a,\\ s_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^2 s_{1k}s_{(j-k)i},$$

for $i = 2\ldots N$, $j=1\ldots 2$, $s_{i0}=s_{0j} = 1$ and $s_{ij}=0$ if $i<0$ or $j<0$.

I tried coding like this:

```
s[1, 1] := 1 - a;
s[1, 2] := a;
s[i, 0] := 1;
s[0, j] := 1;

s[i, j] = Refine[Sum[s[1, k] s[i - k, j], {k, 1, 2}],Assumptions -> {i >= 2, 1 <= j <= 2}]
```

But I only get the result

```
a s[-2 + i, j] + (1 - a) s[-1 + i, j]
```

which is in function of the previous $s_{ij}$ and its look like the assumptions are not taken in account (because of the s[-2 + i, j] and s[-1 + i, j] which are assuming negative index values).

I'm new in Mathematica, and if you guys could help I'll be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is okay to use the ":=" or `SetDelayed` command, the plain `Set` command "=" may be simpler for the first few statements, because they have constants on the RHS.  So, we begin with

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
s[1, 1] = 1 - a;
s[1, 2] = a;
```

For the next two statements we need to use the `Blank[]` expression, which is abbreviated with the underscore, as

```
s[_, 0] = 1;
s[0, _] = 1;
```

In the above, there is no need to name the blank, since the name does not appear on the RHS.

Now we can code

```
s[i_, j_] := Simplify[Sum[s[1, k] s[i - k, j], {k, 1, 2}]]
```

Here, we need to name the blanks and use the the ":=" symbol, because $i$ and $j$ appear on the RHS.  Also, we could have coded this `SetDelayed` before the `Set` statements, but the more general cases are usually defined after the more specific cases.

Now we can try to find s[1,3], but if we do we will get an error, because we have left something out.  When $i$ is 1 and $k$ is 2, we get an s[-1,3] in our sum, and that is a problem.

So, we can add the statement  `s[-1,_] = 0;`
Now we can make a table of values of $s_{ij}$ like this

```
t = Table[s[irow, jcol], {irow, 0, 4}, {jcol, 1, 3}]
t // TableForm
```

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1-a & a & 1-a \\
 a^2-a+1 & -(a-2) a & a^2-a+1 \\
 -a^3+a^2-a+1 & a \left(a^2-2
   a+2\right) & -a^3+a^2-a+1 \\
 a^4-a^3+a^2-a+1 & -a \left(a^3-2
   a^2+2 a-2\right) & a^4-a^3+a^2-a+1
   \\
\end{array}$

**Edit 1:**

Also, since the expression for `s[i,j]` is a recursion relation, to avoid recalculating the values of $s_{ij}$ you may want to use

```
s[i_, j_] := s[i, j] = Sum[s[1, k] s[i - k, j], {k, 1, 2}] // Simplify
```

instead of the first definition.  This new definition tells MMA to save the intermediate values, which uses more memory, but will be faster if you need to calculate many values $s_{ij}$ for large $i$ and $j$.

**Edit 2:**

Now claim there are only two unique columns in any table `t` with any number of rows and columns calculated as above.  This conjecture seems obvious by inspection using a large number of rows and column.  Here's how we can verify the claim for a few rows and columns.  First take the transpose, which gives a list of the columns.  Then drop the second element and use `Union` to get a list of unique columns.  There is only one element, so there is only one unique column, except for the second column.  Here's the code:

```
t = Table[s[irow, jcol], {irow, 0, 50}, {jcol, 1, 30}];
Drop[Transpose[t], 2] // Union // Length
```

A second conjecture is the $i$-th row of the first column can be written as $s_{i,1}=\Sigma_{k=0}^i(-a)^k$.  We can find another form for this expression with

```
Sum[(-a)^k, {k, 0, i}]//Factor
```

$\frac{a (-a)^i+1}{a+1}$

That's the closed form for the $s_{i,j\neq 2}$.  We can get a closed form for $s_{i2}$ by a third conjecture that the $i$-th row of the second column of table $t$ is $s_{i,2}=2+(-a)^i-2\Sigma_{k=0}^i(-a)^k$.  Here's the code

```
Factor[ 2 + (-a)^i - 2 Sum[(-a)^k, {k, 0, i}] ]
```

$\frac{(-a)^i+(-a)^{i+1}+2 a}{a+1}$

To prove the conjectures using Mathematica, searching this forum for "induction" would be a good first step.  Also, replacing $a$ with $-b$ from the beginning could make the expressions simpler in an induction proof.

Comment: LouisB, your answer clarified me a lot about the language. Thank you very much.
My only question now is that if I can find a general solution for the series that only depends of $a$,$i$ and $j$. The general solution that mathematica found was:

   s[i,j] =  a s[-2 + i, j] - (-1 + a) s[-1 + i, j]
I'm trying to find a general solution which looks like:

   s[i,j] =  a [something in function of 'a','i' and 'j'] - (-1 + a) [something in function of 'a','i' and 'j']

But I dont know if the series above can be wrote in this way.

Comment: Correcting my last comment.
I want to find something like:

s[i,j] = a [something in function of 'a','i' and 'j'] - (-1 + a) [something in function of 'a','i' and 'j'] 

for $i\geq2$ and $1\leq j\leq2$.

Comment: Look at the column $s_{i,1}$ .  It is the same as all the other columns, except for column $s_{i,2}$.  It looks like there could be one closed form expression for $s_{i,2}$ and another closed form for the other columns.  I am ignoring column $s_{i,0}$, which is all ones.  Maybe Mathematica can find the closed forms, maybe not.

Comment: It looks like the second column is $s_{i,2}=2+(−a)^i−2\Sigma(−a)^k$ and the other columns are $s_{i,j}=\Sigma(−a)^k$ when $j\neq 2$, with the sums over $k$ running from 0 to $i$, but I haven't checked it.  Earlier comment said 1 to $k$, which was clearly wrong.